Visual Studio 2022 Debug Browser show up without url header and dev tools
I am using Visual Studio 2022 ASP.Net Core 6 MVC
Th Problem is Visual Studio Debug Browser shows up with no header and no access dev tools
The problem persist if javascript is enabled
browser
This is perfectly fine if i change to other browser beside google
Other Project beside it works fine only this specific project
I tried deleting bin ,objects and .vs but the problem persist
I even re-install google chrome but it doesnt help
I temporary remove js file still doesnt help too
CS PROJ:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common" Version="6.0.31" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.24.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.GridFS" Version="2.24.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB" Version="5.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\Areas\" />
    <Folder Include="Common\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Hi dags, from your description, seems it's not related to the vs2022/browser settings. Could you kindly share your .csproj file, it remember there are some package can implement this similar thing.

I want to check if there is something like Electron.NET exist in your project.

Thanks for your reply @JasonPan,
Here's all the package installed in my project,
AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore Version="6.0.16"    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design Version="6.0.16"    MongoDB.Driver Version="2.24.0"    MongoDB.Driver.GridFS" Version="2.24.0"    Serilog.AspNetCore Version="6.1.0"    Serilog.Settings.Configuration Version="8.0.0"    Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB Version="5.4.1"
This is the only project that the problem persist, i have similar project with
ASP.net core 8 MVC this problem doesnt happen.

Hi dags, please share all the code in .csproj. We also want to know if the same problem occurs when opening this project on another PC. If possible, please simplify this project and share it with us for investigation.

@JasonPan thanks for reply,
opening this project on another PC
will try this suggestion as soon as another pc will be available .
So far i tried creating a new project with every package installed the issue didnt araise in the new project.
I also included the csproj, Please see the updated question above

Hi dags, this issue is very interesting. If you can reproduce the issue in another PC, could you simplify this project and share it with us?
